# Slick 3 transaction how to

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Trying to wrap my head around the slick 3 api.

I have these method signatures:

```
  def findById(id: Long): DBIO[Option[Project]] =
Projects.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption

  def insert(Task: Task): DBIO[Long] =
Tasks returning Tasks.map(_.id) += Task
```

which i want to run in a single transaction in my controller.

My code currently looks like this and is not transactional:

```
def addTaskToProject(taskName: String, projectId: Long) = Action.async { implicit rs =>

  val query = for {
    Some(project) <-  projectDAO.findById(projectId)
    id <- taskDAO.insert(Task(0, "blue", project.id))
  }yield id

  val result = dbConfig.db.run(query)

  result.map{ taskId =>
    Ok("I have created a new task: " + taskId)
  }
}
```

1) I tried doing just this:

```
val result = dbConfig.db.run(query).transactionally
```

but that gave me this error:

```
... value transactionally is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Long]
```

2) Then i tried this:

```
val result = dbConfig.db.run(query.transactionally)
```

and got this error:

```
... value transactionally is not a member of slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Long,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.All with slick.dbio.Effect.All]
```

How can i get this trivial example to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

transactionally is function of DBIO, 
try this:

```
val result = dbConfig.db.run(query.transactionally)
```

P.S. actually there is a implicit conversion from `DBIOAction` to `JdbcActionExtensionMethods` that has `transactionally` function

Comment: thanks for the hint. did not work yet (see question). how would i apply the implicit converstion?

Comment: Found it. The problem was that this was missing: import dbConfig.driver.api._